# iPad Mini display error when dismissing keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a strange error that show up only on iPad Mini's.

Our application has login screen, which is a UIViewController conforming to the UIScrollView protocol.

When typing in the login details and hitting the login button, the keyboard is dismissed. However on the iPad Mini, when the keyboard is dismissed, there are small moving white lines in the view controller.
It looks almost like screen tearing or a trail left by the keyboard animating out, but it is above where the keyboard was.

I will try to get hold of a screenshot from our tester. This ONLY happens on iPad Mini's.

Is there a special consideration for animations on the mini I am not aware of, when dismissing keyboards? I've been researching this for 2 hours and I can't find anything.

Comment: this might be issue of screen resolution.check your image sizes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to take a look. 
We do set the display scale for images, and we use the naming convention to support both normal and retina displays.

Will give feedback once I know

Comment: We have an image that moves down along with the keyboard. This is definitely cause the problem. I'm just not sure why.

Comment: how this  image that moves down along with the keyboard?

Comment: When we show the keyboard, we set the images frame to move higher, and when we dismiss the keyboard, we set the images frame to move lower.

It creates the lines when moving down.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Just to answer this question:

The fuzziness on the image and the artefacts when the images changes position is cause by the fact that the UIImageView which contained the image had different dimensions than the image did.
This would cause the UIImageView to end up on a fractional value pixel after a transform.
As the iPad Mini which had the problem is not a retina device, the OS would then attempt to Anti-alias the UIImageView, which would in turn cause a fuzzy image, and the trails left when the image moves.

The solution was fairly simple, on the XIB file for the controller, select the UIImageView containing the image, then on the 'Editor' menu, select 'Size to Fit Content'.
(Or with the UIImageView selected use the Command + '=' shortcut)